# How do I get list of arrays in one line instead of rows in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, visual-studio-code

When I run this code in VSCode

```
var Window = function(tabs) {
  this.tabs = tabs; // We keep a record of the array inside the object
};

// When you join two windows into one window
Window.prototype.join = function (otherWindow) {
  this.tabs = this.tabs.concat(otherWindow.tabs);
  return this;
};

// When you open a new tab at the end
Window.prototype.tabOpen = function (tab) {
  this.tabs.push('new tab'); // Let's open a new tab for now
  return this;
};

// When you close a tab
Window.prototype.tabClose = function (index) {

  // Only change code below this line

  var tabsBeforeIndex = this.tabs.splice( index, 2); // Get the tabs before the tab
  var tabsAfterIndex = this.tabs.splice(index + 1); // Get the tabs after the tab

  this.tabs = tabsBeforeIndex.concat(tabsAfterIndex); // Join them together

  // Only change code above this line

  return this;
 };

// Let's create three browser windows
var socialWindow = new Window(['FB', 'Gitter', 'Reddit', 'Twitter', 'Medium']); // Social sites
var videoWindow = new Window(['Netflix', 'YouTube', 'Vimeo', 'Vine']); // Entertainment sites
var workWindow = new Window(['GMail', 'Inbox', 'Work mail', 'Docs', 'freeCodeCamp']); // Your mailbox, drive, and other work sites

// Now perform the tab opening, closing, and other operations
var finalTabs = socialWindow
  .tabOpen() // Open a new tab for cat memes
  .join(videoWindow.tabClose(2)) // Close third tab in video window, and join
  .join(workWindow.tabClose(1).tabOpen());
console.log(finalTabs.tabs);
console.log(socialWindow.tabOpen().join(videoWindow.tabClose(2)));
```

The result in my VSCode terminal returns

```
Window {
  tabs: [
    'FB',           'Gitter',
    'Reddit',       'Twitter',
    'Medium',       'new tab',
    'Vimeo',        'Vine',
    'Inbox',        'Work mail',
    'freeCodeCamp', 'new tab',
    'new tab'
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know how I can change columns? I want to view the arrays in one line if possible...
Is there a setting where I can change this? Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a formatter issue. If you are running ESLint or Prettier then it might be set to do that. Try turning off your formatters in settings

Comment: @Jacob I tried disabling prettier and ESlint and restarted VS Code just in case but still the same.. Does disabling the plugins disable all settings in VS Code for related plugins? Or do I need to find settings myself manually and comment them out?

Comment: Not just the plugins, there are VSCode preferences. The formatted settings in there can be overzealous

Comment: @Jacob Didn't find any... How can I describe this in google search? Any idea?

Comment: "VSCode terminal output format configurations"

Comment: No luck.. But thanks for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Dang. I will look into it more after work on my own VSCode, there has to be a way to change how the builtin output is formatted

Comment: @Jacob You da man! Let me know if you find out how.

Comment: @Jacob any luck?

Comment: No. Unfortunately 

Comment: @Jacob  Yeah.. I looked everywhere too and no luck =/ Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Node.js internal API](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html) - `util.inspect`:

```js
console.log(util.inspect(socialWindow.tabOpen().join(videoWindow.tabClose(2)), {compact: true}));
```

or simply put, override the default `console.log`:

```js
const { inspect } = require('util');

let temp = console.log
console = {
  ...console,
  log: (...a) => temp(...a.map(b => inspect(b, { compact: true, breakLength: Infinity })))
}


console.log(socialWindow.tabOpen().join(videoWindow.tabClose(2)));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and answer. I am still not familiar with the backend yet since I'm still learning the front end. My question is where do I insert your code? Or do you mean I have to insert your code on the file I've posted above? If I have to paste this code in somewhere, which file do I need to insert this in to? Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are multiple ways to implement this, you can start by the easiest - insert it within the same file you want to console log (the one you pasted above)